# I can't inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA! Error: inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I'm using MAT_DIALOG_DATA to pass data to my dialog, however, I get this error in my browser console.

```
Uncaught Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:1767)
    at inject (core.js:1778)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

First of all, I have to point out that I'm using angular 7.

I watch many videos and read many articles that show that what I included in my project is enough:
- I imported MAT_DIALOG_DATA from angular material.
- I used dialog reference. 
- I define my injection in the constructor.

here the component.ts codes:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-editor-dialog',
  templateUrl: './table-editor-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-editor-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class TableEditorDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<TableEditorDialogComponent>
   ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getMessageId(id : Number){
  }
}
```

I'm expecting to pass data to the dialog.
What's is going on right now. My program Compiles successfully but inside the browser, the program stops working and show the error from the error.

```
Uncaught Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:1767)
```

Comment: Salam!, watch your imports literals, it's Inject  not  inject

Comment: ` @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data` instead of  `@inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imports should be `Inject`, and not `inject`. So, use the following import

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

And, in the components's constructor

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TableEditorDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
```

**[Correct Injection of MAT_DIALOG_DATA](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-)**

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/     lesson fails to mention you have to import  Inject from core....   thanks!

Comment: thanks @greg for pointing this out. With releases of Angular they must have changed the imports. Your mentioned blog link will help any member facing issue if he/she is using my solution.